# P5 Canvas not showing on mobile device (iOS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I don’t have the portion causing the issue, but the code is available on the website being worked on.

on an iPad device it works mostly, aside from misalignment on loading the page which corrects itself upon reorientation of device. On computer, the website functions responsively at all scales on the browsers/OS I tested. (Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Safari[Mac]) On my iPhone I get a white box where the canvas should be on the page load, which disappears to an empty page.

I tried looking for the problematic cause, but can’t find what the cause of the incompatibility is

Code snippet on p5 editor works for desktop but gets an error for mobile
https://editor.p5js.org/0op0/sketches/wLv5nymoM

Comment: http://designedbydan.art/Projects/p5js-clock/ Website with source code

Comment: Please make an attempt to extract just enough code from that site to show the problem, and put the code into your question, preferably as a runnable snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example